# ConfluentKafka in Python: Using consumer to consumer set of records

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I have started to learn confluent kafka(python). There is 1 producer, 1 topic, 1 partition and 1 consumer(a simple setup). My requirement is that I wish to fetch data collectively. I read that using poll(some_time) will wait for the required time and fetch records in batches/list. I thought it would be a simple iteration process, something like:

msgs = consumer.poll(1000)
for msg in msgs:
do some action..........

Issue is I can't iterate over this 'msgs' object - I scanned to documentation to realize poll returns a single message - so is there no way to get a list of messages?(A workaround would be to frequently fetch in subsets of that required time, then process data collectively - but was hoping there was another way). The poll() iteration process appears to be different from kafka-python's way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poll method in python doesn't inherently support batch processing, so as you mentioned:  "*a workaround would be to frequently fetch in subsets of that required time, then process data collectively*"

See this [article](https://wkkan.medium.com/poll-batches-of-kafka-messages-with-python-and-confluent-kafka-3b5d331b2f4e), it can help you

Comment: I tried this before, but received the following error:

    for tp, records in msgs.items():
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'cimpl.Message' object has no attribute 'items'

Are you sure it returns a dictionary - that's something apache-kafka did I believe.

Comment: My bad, I thought batch consuming exists in Python as another languages like Java.
I have deleted what I have written before. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's weird how they didn't include a basic functionality like this - I'm not sure if multiple poll calls are even efficient in such context.

Answer (score 2):

You need a while loop. It's written in the documentation and the runnable examples in the github repo...

Confluent library is implemented over a C/C++ client, not natively implemented in Python like kafka-python or aiokafka, therefore won't directly have a native Python iterable object to use. The Kafka consumer protocol *does* do pre-fetching though, so you're actually polling from a local queue, not actual making one network call for an offset at a time. See `queued.min.messages` - https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

If you'd like this iterator feature available, search the github issues. I'm sure someone would want the same thing.

Comment: Thanks ! I remember their pre-fetching concept. However,while interpreting confluent's poll(some_time)- i guess the 'some_time' is irrelevant(from fetching perspective) - every call just fetches 1 record, so I believe I just need to poll rather frequently? Is this assertion correct?

Comment: It's not irrelevant. When the local queue is exhausted, that timeout will be used on the next fetch call and block to refill the local queue